# Outlook [Add-in] for Mac not supporting OfficeJS Mailbox 1.10 and it should?

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

According to table in this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

Outlook for Mac - With "New Outlook" toggled on should support OfficeJS API Mailbox 1.10

My code

```
const isMinOfficeSdkSupported = Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported(
  'MailBox',
  '1.10'
);
```

is returning false. And when I check version

```
Office.context.diagnostics.version
```

returns "16.53.912.0" which also falls under the supported version shown in the documentation on that page found on Footnote 4.

I specifically require `getComposeTypeAsync` for my add-in feature to work correctly (added in Mailbox 1.10).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does the `getComposeTypeAsync` method work correctly?

Comment: It will work correctly on any other clients that support Mailbox 1.10, yes. (outlook web, and/or the windows client)

Comment: Your version -  "16.53.912.0" falls under the supported versions. Does this method works for you while `isSetSupported` returns false?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, correct isSetSupported returns false.  (I updated description above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replied to OP: Officejs API set 1.10 is not supported on 16.53.912.0, Please update your Outlook to latest.

Comment: Where is this documented? I cannot find that information anywhere.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch : Its called in this document that for Outlook on the new Mac UI preview, the minimum required build is 16.54 (21101001).